# What is the value of __name__ when accessed in a __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

My current understanding is that, when one writes `from foo import bar`, `foo` which is a package and has `__init__.py`, will have its `__init__.py` automatically processed after which its resource `bar` will be imported. If from the command prompt, I write `python manage.py`, and in that module call `from foo import bar`, in the `__init__.py` which belongs to foo package, is the variable `__name__` then equal to the package name? foo in this case?

Comment: This wouldn't be difficult to determine with a simple experiment.  Try writing the value of `__name__` and see what it is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `__init__` module of a package, `__name__` is set to the name of the package; e.g. what the module is stored under in `sys.modules`.

For a package `foo`, `__name__` is set to `'foo'`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('foo')
>>> open('foo/__init__.py', 'w').write('print "__name__:", __name__')
>>> open('foo/bar.py', 'w').write('# nothing done here')
>>> from foo import bar
__name__: foo
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['foo']
<module 'foo' from 'foo/__init__.py'>
>>> sys.modules['foo'].__name__
'foo'
```

Note that *each Python module* has such a `__name__` variable; even the initial script. If you run `python manage.py` the initial script is loaded as the `__main__` module, so *in `manage.py` the name is set to `'__main__'`; this name does not change with what is imported by the script.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? (I believe it, I just couldn't find it in writing anywhere to cite while I was writing an answer of my own.)

Comment: @chepner: In Python 2, how packages are handled during importing is rather sparsely documented in different locations. Python 3 [does make it explicit](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages): *When a regular package is imported, this `__init__.py` file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.*; and [`__name__` is defined as the fully qualified name of the module](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__name__).

Comment: @chepner: Since `__init__.py` is implicitly loaded, and bound to the package's namespace (and not one of its own), the fully qualified name is that of the package.

Answer (score -3):

`__name__` belongs to the local scope (attribute) of the module that you call with python, ie: in this case `manage.py`.

Comment: The question asks about `__name__` **in `foo/__init__.py`**, not in `manage.py`. Because `manage.py` is the main entry script, `__name__` will be set to `'__main__'` instead.